# Does OpenGL only update screen for vSync fps?

Tags: c++, opengl, hook, gdi+, gdi

I hooked wglSwapBuffers to make text overlays.

I just draw text on HDC(wglSwapBuffers(HDC hdc)) with GDI
and it's flickering if fps is over my screen refresh rate.

Is it GDI problem or OpenGL problem?

Here is my code

```
HWND hwnd;
RECT rect;

hwnd = WindowFromDC(context);
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);

DrawText(context, str, strlen(str), &rect, DT_CENTER);
```

(ps. I didn't wanted to use OpenGL to draw texts becouse I don't want to use any librarys with it (like FreeType)

Comment: It sounds as if you're using a single front buffer. Did you enable front-and-back buffering?

Comment: lol....rip my grammer. im not really good at english btw.

Answer (score 1):

If a Win32 window has OpenGL initialized on it, then you *cannot* perform GDI drawing with it anymore. OpenGL is mutually exclusive with Windows drawing functions.

Answer (score 0):

Under win32 you can render text in OpenGL without using any external libraries.
First initialize your fonts (needs to be done only once):

```
const int NR_CHARS = 256;
int m_FontListBase = glGenLists(NR_CHARS);
wglUseFontBitmaps(wglGetCurrentDC(), 0, NR_CHARS-1, m_FontListBase);
```

And then when you want to print any text to your OpenGL context:

```
glRasterPos3f(x, y, z);
glPushAttrib(GL_LIST_BIT);
glListBase(m_FontListBase);  //indicate start of glyph display lists
glCallLists(GLsizei(strlen(str)), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, str);  //draw the characters in str
glPopAttrib();
```

Comment: Since he's hooking into an OpenGL application from the outside, it's dangerous to assume anything about its context. Like whether it's a compatibility context, which your code relies on.